# DISPLAY=:0: Command not found

Tags: centos, display, tcsh

```
user@domain:~ $ echo $DISPLAY
:0
user@domain:~ $ DISPLAY=:0
DISPLAY=:0: Command not found.
```

Just trying to run the command here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46810043/notify-send-doesnt-work-over-ssh - How come it's not recognized as a command? I'm using CentOS v7.7.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact command you are typing? Are you not leaving a space before or after the equal sign, such as `DISPLAY = :0`?

Comment: Also, which shell are you using?

Comment: I am using tcsh, and yeah I'm using DISPLAY=:0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tcsh` has different syntax from Bash. To set your variable in that shell and make it available for the programs you'll call, you have to use the following command:

```
setenv DISPLAY :0
ssh ....
```

Or if you want that variable only to launch `ssh` (as mentioned in the answer you linked), you can use `env` before the command:

```
env DISPLAY=:0 ssh ......
```

Comment: The `set`  command will not put the variable into the environment. For that you need `setenv DISPLAY :0` (three words, no `=`)

Comment: Thank you. I have amended my answer to include your correction.

Comment: you're the champ!